# Prolog - Accessing list variable from a nth0/3

Tags: prolog

Consider the following case:

```
card([a,b,c,d,e]).
```

How can I access this list, in a new nth0/3 function without redefining the list elements in it?

Example:

```
?- nth0(2, card, X).
X = c
```

I tried looking online but all of them had the list defined in the nth0 itself.

So my question is, is it possible to do something like this? If so, how?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `nth0/3` it doesn't take a predicate as a second argument. It expects a list. Prolog predicates do not "return" values like functions do in other languages. So `card` doesn't "return" the value of `X` in `card(X)`. Daniel's answer shows the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would obtain the value of `card/1` would be to supply it to a query, like this:

```
?- card(Card), nth0(2, Card, X).
```

Since the capitals are variables, this is going to be about the same as if you did something like this:

```
?- Card = [_,_,X,_,_].
```

I fear you are hoping to see some state between queries, but Prolog doesn’t do that. In your next query, `card/1` will again just be a list of five unknown elements. For this reason, your `card/1` definition smells fishy to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited my question. the elements in the list are just elements, not any variables. A common mistake made by a prolog newbie, not forgetting about case sensitive.

Comment: @NewbieCoder in that case, is the first part of my answer helpful?

Comment: Very. Thanks alot!